# Fill out notebook

Tags: java

Good evening,
I want to do a method that inserts contacts by row into an empty notebook and sorts the names alphabetically and I've already done this but I'm currently stuck:

```
StringBuffer contactCarnet = new StringBuffer(contactLigne);
        contactCarnet.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        String contact = String.valueOf(contactCarnet);
        return contact;
```

But I don't see how to sort contacts by name without using an array and the collections -_- class someone could give me a hand, a tip please. Thank you and good day!

Comment: What do you mean by "notebook"? Do you want to write data to an Excel file? Or is writing a CSV file sufficient? Or do you mean something else? What do you mean by "names" and "contacts"? Do you have data that represents a contact? How do you store and manipulate these contacts in yoru code? We need to see a more complete example in order to answer your questions. It will help if you show us what `contactLigne` and `contactCarnet` are.

Comment: Hi i want to do a method who  inserts the given line contact in the given book (who is a String) empty and the contact must be inserted respecting the alphabetical order of the surnames. I did a small part of the code but i don't see how to sort surnames without importing a class for example java.util.Arrays or java.util.Collections, thanks for the help !

Comment: I forgot, i can use the class StringTokenizer and Scanner but not another class

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to solve everything at once. You need to back up and break the problem into individual pieces. The first thing I would solve is how you represent contacts in your program. One possible solution is to create your own `class Contact` that stores all the data for a contact. Next you need to figure out how you store multiple contacts. You have at least two options here: an array or an `ArrayList`. Alternatively, you can write your own `LinkedList` class if this is a learning exercise for writing data structures.